# Current user in sidemenu Ionic

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

First I use Ionic with Firebase. So, I have a component that is the menu of my application, in it I can do the validation if the user is logged in or not and make the necessary redirects, however I can not get the data of the user that is logged in, I tried several forms and only returns me undefinied.

This is my code that come back the user logged. I need to do: `this.currentUser = user;`

```
 this.auth.authenticated().subscribe(
  user => {
    if (user) {
      if (!this.inRegister()) {
        this.currentUser = user;
        this.rootPage = HomePage;
      }
    } else {
      this.rootPage = LoginPage;
    }
  },
  () => {
    this.rootPage = LoginPage;
  }
);
```

This is my `authenticated()` function:

```
authenticated(): Observable<any>{
  return this.fireAuth.authState.map(res => res.toJSON());
}
```

Comment: A observation is that my side menu it's called by the app.component